# When using Spring 3.x docker compose dependency, does jar file include my docker-compose.yml images?

Tags: spring

My question is exactly same as the title.
I'm using Spring 3.x version, gradle with docker compose dependency.

below is part of my build.gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y96g.png)

below is part of my application.yml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRV8X.png)

and below is the directory which my docker-compose.yaml exists

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ildm.png)

So by this information, whenever my server turns on, the docker containers will be built based on docker-compose.yaml.

But the problem is I want them to be in .jar files so I can use it in AWS ec2.

when I "./gradlew clean build"

.jar file is generated but when I try to execute by cmd "java -jar app.jar"
then it won't work. It will say if can't find docker-compose.yaml directory.

Is docker compose dependency isn't meant to work this way?
or is there a solution to this?